# How to set the scale bar correctly in print layout

Tags: qgis, scale, well-known-text

In the print layout, the layer uses custom projection, and the correct scale cannot be set.
I want to use kilometers as the scale bar, but this custom layer can only use map units as the scale bar, but I don't know the meaning of map units.
WTK parameters：

```
PROJCRS["Albers",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["EPSG",6326]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]],
    CONVERSION["unnamed",
        METHOD["Albers Equal Area",
            ID["EPSG",9822]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8821]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",105,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8822]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",25,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8823]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",47,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8824]],
        PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8826]],
        PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8827]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
```

Comment: I believe `LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]` indicates that your map unit is 1m. So your scalebar would be in meters.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I change it to kilometers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also see weird behaviour using your custom CRS and the print composer scale bar. When changing to "kilometers" as scale bar units the values are clearly off by a factor of 1000. Entering "1000" in the field which is called "Beschriftungseinheitsfaktor" in my german translation of QGIS (don't know the english field name, roughly "label unit scale factor") probably corrects the issue.

Sample print layout

[image: sample layout with mentioned field set to 1000]

Comment: Thank you very much. I found that if the kilometer is used as the unit of scale, the scale will become abnormal. As Mr xsquared said, the map unit of this custom CRS is meters. If beschriftungseinheitsfaktor is changed to 1000, it may be that meters are changed into kilometers