# Is there any way to link the current map scale in the print layout to a text box?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, scale, update, link

Is there any way to link the current map scale in the print layout?

I know you can do something similar with the the date by entering $CURRENT_DATE(yyyy-MM-dd) into the text box.

Comment: What do you mean by "current map"? Do you just want to add a scale to your map just like the image in the  [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/428358/how-to-set-the-scale-bar-correctly-in-print-layout?rq=1)?

Comment: I am in the print composer and have inserted a map with a custom scale. I do not want to use a scale bar, but rather display the scale as text in a text box I have created. 

I usually manually update the scale in the text box, but I was wondering if there was something I could type into the text box which links it to the scale of the map on the print composer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a scale bar. After adding, right-click the scale bar, select Item properties and change Main properties - Style to Numeric and you can round the numbers by customizing the Units - Number format

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Under text box is a button labelled "dynamic text" here you can choose different information that will be added into the text dynamically. It can also grab information from other items in the layout. you can also further edit the grabbed information.In the picture I rounded the scale value for readability. Instead of going with the box you can also write the expression directly. `[%item_variables('Map 1')['map_scale']%]`[image: dynamic text options]

Comment: This is great thank you. Do you know how to add in a comma separator and change the decimal places of the scale when using this function?

Comment: using format_number will give you those options

Answer (score 0):

If you ever need to place the scale in the table you can use this (change 'Map 1' to the name of your map)

```
'1:'||round(map_get(item_variables('Map 1'),'map_scale'),0)
```

This if pasted into a table field will give you scale formatted as 1:x.